# grep("A" & "comp") gives error

Tags: r

I have been stuck on this for hours, please give me some helps !

I got a file contains thousands of observations and they are in rows/lines (no columns)

So I do readLines and then want to extract the data that I need

```
#open file for data connection
data <- file("data.log", open = "r")

#do readlines for the first 6 lines tho
##there should be more than  500 lines for thousands of observations
rl <- readLines(data, 6)
```

the labels/headers that are not included in the data: time , group, task, complete or not, hours, credit

```
 [1]  10:00 A task1 comp 5:00 200                                                                
 [2]  16:00 A task2 comp 3:00 130                                                                    
 [3]  11:00 B task1 incomp 7:00 180                                                                                
 [4]  17:00 B task2 comp 7:00 100                                                      
 [5]  15:00 C task1 incomp 5:00 420                                               
 [6]  19:00 C task2 comp 6:00 115
```

so there are 2 things I want to extract and then put them into a data frame.
I want to get the group "A" with "comp"
so I tried grep()

```
grep("A", data)
```

but I got the result: integer (0)
also, how can I grep() both A and comp at the same time?

I tried :

```
grep "A", data | grep "comp"

grep("A" & "comp", data)
```

both give error!

any help would be appreciated !! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the results you want from the dataset you've put in your question, but you might want to look at the help entry for `grep` to see how to manipulate it further.

```
grep(
  x = rl, 
  pattern = " A .* comp ",
  value = TRUE
)
```

Comment: thanks so much! so I got the result with lines containing "A" with a "comp".

Comment: After that, I used the same code to find lines containing "B" with "comp". it works totally fine
Then I want to write a function that get lines "A" with "comp" followed by "B" with "comp".

Comment: here's my code:

  `ext = function(filename = "data.log")
  {
    rl = readLines(data)
    result = grep(
      x = rl, 
      pattern = " A .* comp ",
      value = TRUE)
    
    if(length(result) == 1){
      rl = readLines(data)
      result = grep(
        x = rl, 
        pattern = " B.* comp ",
        value = TRUE)
      
      if(length(result) == 1) return(result)
      
    }
  }`

somehow there's no response/result after I run the code
ext("data")