# function for grep( pattern = "A.* comp") has no result

Tags: r

refer to my previous post

[grep("A" & "comp") gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904803/grepa-comp-gives-error)

Here's my data :the labels/headers that are not included in the data: time , group, task, complete or not, hours, credit

```
[1]  10:00 A task1 comp 5:00 200                                                                
[2]  16:00 A task2 comp 3:00 130                                                                    
[3]  11:00 B task1 incomp 7:00 180                                                                                
[4]  17:00 B task2 comp 7:00 100                                                      
[5]  15:00 C task1 incomp 5:00 420                                               
[6]  19:00 C task2 comp 6:00 115
```

I got help from @Codoremifa about how to grep lines that have both "A" and "comp"

I used the same code to get lines that have "B" with a "comp" which works totally fine.
Then I tried to do something a bit more complicated:

Get lines contain "A" with "comp" and then the next line is "B" with "comp".

I wrote the first function which seems to be work, but when I run it with ext(data), there's no result.

```
ext = function(filename = "data")
{
    rl = readLines(log)
    result = grep(
    x = rl,
    pattern = " A .* comp ",
    value = TRUE)

    if(length(result) == 1){
        rl = readLines(data)
        result = grep(
        x = rl, 
        pattern = " B.* comp ",
        value = TRUE)

 if(length(result) == 1) return(result)

 }
}
```

somehow there's no response when I do ext(data)

I also tried using `print()` instead of `return()`
And using `if(result ==1)` instead of `if(length(result)==1)`
But it's still not working.

Please help me out !! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this peace of code there is nothing that tell that "the next line is "B" with "comp"". 
But it might not work because you said that only if `length(result)` is 1 do it instead of different to 0 or equal or more than 1 that could be `length(result) != 0` or `length(result) >= 1`

To look if the following line of data has this information you can read just the lines of data that accomplish this condition and then apply again de `grep` function something like:

```
data2<-data[c(result+1), ]
result2 = grep(
    x = data2, 
    pattern = " B.* comp ",
    value = TRUE)
```

And you will get the lines that contain "B" with "comp" and its previous line contained "A" with "comp". I hope it works

Comment: Thanks @Llopis ! so for the code length(result)==1, I have changed it to !=0 but it's not working. Also, the code you provided gave an error +1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator - have been searching online for this error but couldn't figure out how to fix it. Please give me some tips! thanks!

Comment: And I just wanna make sure that I would like to get lines as shown in the following:
[1]  10:00 A task1 comp 5:00 200                                                                
[2]  16:00 B task2 comp 3:00 130                                                                    
[3]  11:00 A task1 comp 7:00 180                                                                                
[4]  17:00 B task1 comp 7:00 100                                                      

task1 or 2 doesn't matter.

Comment: I tried the strsplit to split it by space and grep with the column....it also works for just grepping either lines contain "A" with "comp" or "B" with "comp". How can I put them together?

Comment: @user2978129 Could you print what `dput(data)` says just to probe if it works before changing my answer. And the error is because result is character and it tries to do some numeric operators to it. (That's why I ask for de dput, just to make a complete code)